# JQuery do something after DOM element is created - DOMNodeInserted not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I have one empty div, which is dynamically filled with some content later:

```
<div class="row no-margin">
    <div id="sensorInfoContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

Later it is filled with some other divs and content. I need to select this child div:

```
<div class="circDash" id="batPerc" accesskey="30" style="height:100px; background-color:#000000;">
```

And call this function on it:

```
$(*DIV*).circleProgress({
            value: 0.75,
            size: 80,
            fill: {
                gradient: ["red", "orange"]
           }
        });
```

I tried to do that on click, and it's working. Like this:

```
$('#sensorInfoContent').on("click", ".circDash", function() {

    $(this).circleProgress({
        value: 0.75,
        size: 80,
        fill: {
            gradient: ["red", "orange"]
       }
    });
});
```

But I need it to be done after element is dynamically added, not on click. Tried `DOMNodeInserted`, it's not working:

```
    $('#sensorInfoContent').on("DOMNodeInserted", ".circDash", function() {

        $(this).circleProgress({
            value:

 0.75,
        size: 80,
        fill: {
            gradient: ["red", "orange"]
       }
    });
});
```

Any ideas, alternatives or work-arounds?

Comment: `which is dynamically filled with some content later` How are you doing this? Presumably you're using AJAX, if so just use a callback function.

Comment: How you "dinamically add" the div?

Comment: Hmm, I'll check it out. Back end is created with mostly Java, Java Scala, don't know if Ajax is used for this.

Still hoping if it could be solved in some simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it on my own, by blind guessing.

Script code was initially written on the top of the page, now I put the script below this .circDash div and it's working! :D

It was just about script positioning, I guess now script is running after div is created.

I am new in JQuery/JS so... This might be a rookie mistake. :D Cheers!

EDIT: If someone wants and knows to answer on why function `on.("click",...` worked and function `on.("DOMNodeInserted",...` didn't, that would be the best answer on this all, regardless of my solved solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the click manually

```
$('#sensorInfoContent').on("click", ".circDash", function() {

    $(this).circleProgress({
        value: 0.75,
        size: 80,
        fill: {
            gradient: ["red", "orange"]
       }
    });
});
```

Like this

```
$('.circDash').trigger('click');
```